# Alias gedit to accept an argument

Tags: bash, alias, arguments, csh

This alias works in UNIX and in Redhat.   It does not work in Fedora

```
alias te 'gedit "\!*" &'
```

Usage:   `te myfile.cpp`

It opens gedit with `myfile.cpp` in the edit window and runs in the background.

Is it Fedora that is the problem, or do I need to tweek the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

That's a `csh`-style alias, and my guess is that on Fedora you're now using `sh` or `bash`.  You can either change your shell to `/bin/csh` or `/usr/bin/tcsh` if they are installed or rewrite the alias as a function in your `~/.profile`.

```
function te() {
    gedit "$@" &
}
```

NOTE: The `function` keyword is optional.  Some versions of bourne-style shells require it, some versions don't understand or want it.  Some will work with or without it.

PS: welcome to the Bourne shell club. `csh` and `tcsh` have many problems that bourne-style shells do not have.